# Problem with relative url when linking to external site

Tags: php, url, mariadb, grocery-crud

I recently installed Grocery CRUD to manage my site. The site is written in php and using mariadb to store the content.
I have also activated the CKeditor.
Everything works well and i can write an article and "upload" this to my DB.
In the articles i often want to link to another sites, this should be straight forward, but its not.
When the article is displayed on my website, the URL format is wrong, relative??

Example:
Inputs **`<a href="https://www.test.com">https://www.test.com</a>`** 
Expect to see **https://www.test.com** as a clickable link.
This is the result now when looking at the code: **`<a href="\"https://www.test.com\"">https://www.test.com</a>`** 
When hoovering over the link i see **`https://www.my_domain.com/"https://www.test.com/`**
I am used to correct this in some situations by adding https://, but this doesnt work in this case.

Im not sure where the error/mistake can be found.
Is it the DB that needs some adjustment, is it the CRUD software and particularly the CKeditor that generates this?
Maybe some PHP issue somewhere?

I need some advice/help on this please.
Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: please post your db value so I can see if it's a db problem or code conversion problem

Comment: Hi, can you try formatting your post a little? Stackoverflow supports Markdown so you can can use code blocks instead of trying to escape HTML (?). Additionally, as per markdown, you can use two spaces at the end of a line to add a line break instead of making a big paragraph

Comment: Hi @YellowAfterlife i have done some editing to my post now. Hopefully its more easy to understand.

Comment: Hi @OtávioBarreto Which values do you want me to post? Any particular values you want? Just asking so i can give accurate information.

Comment: @Chriz the column that stores the link , so I can understand if it's a db store problam or your code conversion with the db value

Comment: @OtávioBarreto Here is the column that stores the article text and links if used. Hope this help, if not i can provide more info. Not able to post a screenshot it seems. `long_desc` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
Name
long_desc,

Datatype
TEXT,

Length/Set,

Unsigned,

Allow NULL
NOT NULL,

Zerofill
DEFAULT,

Default
",


COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=472

Comment: @Chriz the column format should not matter at all, I wanna see the column content, how it's stored, if so this way will be easier to know what is the problem if it's on `insert db script` of on `select script`

Answer (score 0):

Too many quotes:

```
<a href="\"https://www.test.com\"">https://www.test.com</a>
```

The pair of `\"` is an escaped quotes, as if it is inside some other pair of `"`.  The plain pair of `"` are ok, too.  HTML needs *either* pair, *not both*.  MariaDB does not care, it is just a string.

MariaDB will not cause that to happen.  However, the code that does the `INSERT` may be screwed up.  Let's see that code in Grocery.

Comment: i think i have found whats causing the problem i had with the urls. `$long_desc = $row["long_desc"];` URL works as normal when $mysqli_connection->real_escape_string is removed.

`$long_desc = $mysqli_connection->real_escape_string($row["long_desc"]);` With $mysqli_connection->real_escape_string the urls gets escaped or something like that.

Comment: I would expect the backslashes to be added, but not the extra set of quotes.